# Are you eligible for FMLA leave if the event occurred while you were not eligible?

Tags: labor-law, pennsylvania

Consider the scenario where you work for an FMLA eligible employer, and are not a key employee. During the time period you are not eligible for FMLA, your partner gives birth to a child. You become eligible for FMLA about 3 months after the child's birth. Are you eligible to take FMLA leave at that time?